# Current through a battery

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

Today was my first class in circuits.(I am moving to 11th grade).
We were given the following circuit.
[image]

After analyzing potential differences and finding current in the resistor , we found that current across positive terminal of $ab$ battery and $a$ should be 2A.
After that he claimed that current across negative terminal of the (same) $ab$ battery and $b$ should also be 2A.
I didn't quite get it even after asking him(According to him it is trivial)

Is it true in general that current across the positive terminal till junction $=$ current across the negative terminal till the other junction?[image]

Further if that is true how does one explain discharging/charging of a battery.
[image]

Comment: Thank you everyone for such quick response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both examples is true. The klmn current in the second example is 2 amperes.

The current going into a battery or resistor always equals the current coming out of a battery or resistor. The same applies to other circuit components (capacitors and inductors). The reason is conservation of charge. Current is the amount of charge passing a point per unit time. The charge going into a component equals the charge going out of the component. Otherwise charge would have to either go to something else or come from something else.

One other thing. We speak of current going through something, not across something. On the other hand we speak of voltage across something and not through something.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that you refer to is a consequence of charge neutrality and the fact that charges are conserved (they don't come out of nowhere). If the ingoing current through the left terminal was different from the outgoing current through the right terminal, net charge would have to collect in the middle (the battery). With that I don't mean charge separation inside the battery (which then would remain neutral, as usual), but the battery as a whole becoming positively or negatively charged and your hair bending towards it.

But even then, the charges must come from somewhere. If the positive plate of the battery becomes more positive, but the negative plate stays the same, the charges have to come from somewhere else. And through the outlet of that "somewhere else" has to flow again the same current as through the inlet of your battery.

For electronic circuits, this discussion is rather artificial because separating significant charges over longer distances requires a huge lot of energy, which is usually not accessible. In a capacitor charges get actually separated, but over very small distances, and what you see there is: although current flows to one plate, **there is no current at all between that plate and the other plate**. Only at the other plate there is again an outgoing current, just like it was taught to you. Only because the capacitor is so small, you do not notice the interruption of current between the plates.

Now comes the crucial point: the fact that charges are conserved, even if current is interrupted, for example at the plate of a capacitor, is **not at all trivial**, contrary to what your teacher says. It took a genius like James Clerk Maxwell, the inventor of the equations of electrodynamics as we know them today, to see the importance of charge conservation, and that the equations of electrodynamics would have to be corrected (with respect to their older form back in 1800-something), in order for charge conservation to be true even for a capacitor.

The result of this correction was the introdcution of the so-called displacement current. Without this introduction, we would never have known that electromagnetic fields spread like waves, no radio, no TV, no mobile phones, etc., etc. What you have correctly been stuck with, is the basis of the most exciting single event in the history of science.

Answer (score 1):

The current in a series circuit is the same at all points. The only way to have a different current is to have a junction of more than 2 wires at some point. Then the current can split between different branches of the circuit. As long as you don't have any branching between two points (like between a and b) there is no other path for the charge to go so the current is the same everywhere. Remembre that current is the rate of charge flow. If the rates were different the result will acumulation of charge in some portions of the circuitwhich will grow unlimitedly. A DC circuits assumes a steady state, with no charge accumulations or depletions.
There are situations with charge accumulation, like when you charge a capacitor. In this case the current between the plates of the capacitor is zero whereas through the rest of circuit it is not zero. The result is charge accumulation on the plates. The accumulation of charge results in cutting off the current which becomes zero when the potential difference on the capacitor becames the same as the emf of the battery. The same will happen in series circuit if for an instant charge accumulation would result. It's a delf regulating process. If the current is larger in some portion of the circuit the charge accumulation will take care to bring it back to the equilibrium value. So the steady state is to hae the same current at all points of a series circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of charge that will go out of battery through +ve terminal will be same as the amount that will enter via -ve terminal after going through a loop that's why current at $a$ and $b$ are equal.

Charging and discharging of a battery is a broad topic. Check [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.electrical4u.com/charging-of-battery-and-discharging-of-battery/%23:%7E:text%3DDuring%2520charging%2520of%2520battery%252C%2520the,positive%2520electrode%2520of%2520the%2520battery.%26text%3DDuring%2520charging%2520of%2520battery%252C%2520the%2520secondary%2520battery%2520turns%2520to%2520its,for%2520further%2520discharging%2520of%2520battery.&ved=2ahUKEwikh_nCybzvAhWwIbcAHUb0BzUQFjANegQIAxAF&usg=AOvVaw37bCB8w5UjOBzPdZ2hqTv6&cshid=1616164429432).

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a potential energy difference (ped voltage) between h and c, g and d, f and e for a current to flow in each circuit back to the 10v cell, totalling 2 amps. It may be that the actual voltage of each of the 8v, 6v, and 4v cells in reality is less than stated, to allow a ped for the current flows of 1 amp, 1/3 amp and 2/3 amp respectively. It would be interesting to build this unusual theoretical circuit and simply measure the voltages at each point, plus if any current flows anywhere, or if the cells just balance each other out.

Answer (score -1):

I've used Ohm's Law and Kirchoff's Laws to answer your questions in the comment section below. Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/334801)

Comment: In 1st circuit, drop across each resistor  is 2 v. With 1 ohm, V = iR, 2 = i x 1, so current is 2 a. With 2 ohm resistor, 2 = i x 2, so 1 amp flows, this means the other 1 amp flows h to c through the cell. With 3 ohm resistor 2 = i 3, so 2/3 amp goes from f to e. That leaves 1/3 amp to go g to d. The three currents join up to go c to b: 1 amp + 1/3 amp + 2/3 amp = 2 amp in total returning to the 10 v cell. This obeys Kirchoff's  1st Law for conservation of current and Kirchoff's second law for conservation of voltage. The current going in to a cell is the same as current coming out of a cell.

Comment: @user291781 You can edit your answer with the information you've given in the comment

Comment: Thank you Steeven.

Comment: Steeven, you seem like a helpful person... I've had my first Question, about Time and Energy, closed and the question remains unanswered. Do you know how I can get it re-opened please....Thanks ken.allsopp@hotmail.com